# Specify the machines running program using MPI

Tags: mpi

I am going to do some parallel computing and I'm totally a beginner in this area. I will use MPI to do the parallel work, with Master-Slave model. I now have four machines and want one of them to be the Master Node. However, I don't know how to specify the other machines running the program. Is there a way like specifying the IP address of slave node? How to launch my program? I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Setup

Make sure you have the same directory/file structure on every node. E.g., the executable should be `/home/yan/my_program` on every computer. You can e.g. mount the same directory on every computer via [NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).

[Setup SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html) so that you can login on every slave node from the master node like this:

```
yan@master:~/$ ssh slave1
yan@slave1:~/$
```

This means that the user `yan` has to exist on every computer. If you setup login via [SSH key](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html#openssh-keys), you don't have to enter the password. If you have login via password, you have to enter it when starting the program.

Install [OpenMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) using

```
sudo apt-get install penmpi-bin openmpi-doc libopenmpi-dev
```

You can install an other MPI implementation like MPICH instead.

### Run program

Now, compile your program with `mpicc myprogram.c -o myprogram` (if you are using C; for C++, `mpic++`, etc.) and run it using

```
yan@masternode:~/$ mpirun -n 4 -H master,slave1,slave2,slave3 myprogram
```

Instead of the [machine name](http://www.robgolding.com/blog/2008/11/26/the-hosts-file-in-ubuntu/), you can also use an IP address. `-n` specifies the number of processes. If you omit the option, one process will be started on each machine. You can also use several slots per machine:

```
yan@masternode:~/$ mpirun -n 8 -H master,slave1,slave2,slave3,\
master,slave1,slave2,slave3 myprogram
```

Alternatively, you can write one computer name per line into a `HOSTFILE` and specify it like this:

```
yan@masternode:~/$ mpirun -hostfile HOSTFILE
```

These commands automatically connect to the slave computers via SSH, start the program and set the communication parameters so that the data distribution works automatically and `MPI_Comm_size` and `MPI_Comm_rank` give the number of the current computer and the size of the cluster.

You can see those options by invoking `man mpirun`.

Comment: pretty helpful! Thanks very much!

Comment: Do I need to add the path of my program to PATH?

Comment: Yes, if it's not in the current directory.